# Why ngOnchanges is getting the data through Input() in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, browser, safari

I am passing an object from parent to child. This is working perfectly on chrome but its not working on safari.

parent component :

```
<org-chart-dialog-user-info [data]="infoData"></org-chart-dialog-user-info>
```

child component:

```
@Input() data: any;

ngOnChanges() {
  if (this.data) {
    this.loaded = true;
  } else {
    this.loaded = false;
  }
}
```

The issue its only in safari browser.

Comment: What is your desired behavior? What result do you get in Safari?

Comment: its showing nothing.